# Error moving from Mongoose 5 to Mongoose 6 in preparation for MongoDB version 6 upgrade

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently using Mongoose 5.13.16 for some deployed server software with no problem (connecting to MongoDB Atlas). I install Mongoose 6 and get the error below, and the software fails to run. I can't see the suggested syntax error in the package modules.

The software is called `mfm-form`.

```
Feb 08 15:21:29 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started mfm-form.
Feb 08 15:21:31 ubuntu node[20271]: 23363
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]: /home/ME/Projects/mfm-form/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:1069
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]:         catch {
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]:               ^
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]:     at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]:     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]:     at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]:     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]:     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ME/Projects/mfm-form/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/add_user.js:6:
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]:     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]:     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu node[20271]:     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu systemd[1]: mfm_form.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu systemd[1]: mfm_form.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu systemd[1]: mfm_form.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu systemd[1]: mfm_form.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Feb 08 15:21:32 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped mfm-form.
```

Is it because Mongoose 6 uses promises? I tried putting the mongoose.connection inside an async/await function and that didn't help.

Interestingly, I can use Mongoose 6 in a locally-installed version of my software on Windows with no problem. Just not with the deployed software on the Ubuntu server started with a `systemctl start` command.